# Markerless AR - Find and track empty space on the way to project a video

Tags: python, opencv, augmented-reality

For my markerless AR project, I want to project a video over the wall.

For this, I need to find a plain region on the wall, Anchor this region and use it as the display region.

Usually we have a reference image, from which features are extracted, matched and tracked. But I cant use this method directly since my reference is a plain region.

[Example Display region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6krp.png)

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Tags and markers are just items we use to ensure feature correspondence. They guarantee a fast and accurate way of matching our projection with the image. We don't need them to figure out where we are though. Everything else in the image can serve as features that we can detect. Using a feature extractor like SIFT/SURF/ORB we can check if the extracted features line up with our anchor region. This tutorial should give you a good idea of how to use this: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html

Comment: I agree but here I have to display my video over a flat region which has no uniqueness. Hence feature extraction yields no result.

Comment: You don't have to project your image directly onto features. Even with markers you can just project your image offset from them so long as you have the correspondence. Think of things like the window and the shelf as your markers. You can display stuff between the two. Feature matching gives you a lot of points to use.

Comment: when you set your anchor over the blank wall, you don't just crop out that area and use that to match features. Take the entire picture it comes from and use all of the features. Just remember where your anchored region exists inside of that picture.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. So basically I need to find the offset of blank space from certain objects manually and then by using homography find the equivalent points.

But this will not be generic. What if I want to find the blank space is any video. There should be some generic way right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by generic. If you have a video, you can do feature matching between your current frame and your anchor frame. Using the homography matrix from the match you can put your anchor region into the current frame at the correct position. The bonus to this method, aside from not needing markers, is that it only needs 4 features in view so you can display your projection even when your region is only partially in view.